# Pre loading data from .sql before unit testing throws syntax error

Tags: java, postgresql, spring-boot, unit-testing, springjunit4classrunner

I'm performing unit testing on spring boot app using JPA and SpringJUnit4ClassRunner. for that I have created a configuration file as -

```
@Configuration
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = "base_package_name")
@EnableTransactionManagement
public class JPAConfig {

    @Bean
    public DataSource dataSource() {
        DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();
        dataSource.setDriverClassName("org.postgresql.Driver");
        dataSource.setUrl("jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/employeedb_test");
        dataSource.setUsername("postgres");
        dataSource.setPassword("postgres");

        return dataSource;
    }

    private Properties hibernateProperties() {
        Properties properties = new Properties();
        properties.put("hibernate.dialect", "org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQL9Dialect");        
        properties.put("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto", "create");
        properties.put("hibernate.show_sql", "true");
        properties.put("hibernate.format_sql", "false");
        return properties;
    }

    @Bean(name="entityManagerFactory")
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactoryBean(){

        LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean lcemfb
            = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();

        lcemfb.setDataSource(this.dataSource());
        lcemfb.setPackagesToScan(new String[] {"Package_to_scan"});

        HibernateJpaVendorAdapter va = new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();
        lcemfb.setJpaVendorAdapter(va);

        lcemfb.setJpaProperties(this.hibernateProperties());

        lcemfb.afterPropertiesSet();

        return lcemfb;

    }


    @Bean
    public PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager(){

        JpaTransactionManager tm = new JpaTransactionManager();

        tm.setEntityManagerFactory(
            this.entityManagerFactoryBean().getObject() );

        return tm;

    }

    @Bean
    public PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor exceptionTranslation(){
        return new PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor();
    }
}
```

My test class looks like this -

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes={
        JPAConfig.class,
        TestConfig.class
        })
@SqlGroup({
    @Sql(executionPhase=ExecutionPhase.BEFORE_TEST_METHOD,scripts="classpath:beforeTestRun.sql")
})
public class ExampleTest {
     ...
}
```

now I want to insert data from script file beforeTestRun.sql into entity before running any test. so I added following annotation above my test class(i.e. ExampleTest) -

```
@SqlGroup({
    @Sql(executionPhase=ExecutionPhase.BEFORE_TEST_METHOD,scripts="classpath:beforeTestRun.sql")
})
```

my beforeTestRun.sql contains insert query -

```
INSERT INTO employee(emp_name)
    VALUES ('Jhon Dave');
```

my model class is -

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "employee")
public class Employee {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name="emp_id")
    Integer id;

    @Column(name="emp_name")
    String empName;


    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getEmpName() {
        return empName;
    }
    public void setEmpName(String empName) {
        this.empName = empName;
    }


}
```

now after running test class, it trying to insert from .sql file but eventhough the syntax is correct it throwing an error says -

```
org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.init.ScriptStatementFailedException: Failed to execute SQL script statement #1 of class path resource [beforeTestRun.sql]: INSERT INTO employee(emp_name) VALUES ('Jhon Dave'); nested exception is org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: syntax error at or near "INSERT"
  Position: 1
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.init.ScriptUtils.executeSqlScript(ScriptUtils.java:626)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.init.ResourceDatabasePopulator.populate(ResourceDatabasePopulator.java:254)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.init.DatabasePopulatorUtils.execute(DatabasePopulatorUtils.java:49)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.init.ResourceDatabasePopulator.execute(ResourceDatabasePopulator.java:269)
    at org.springframework.test.context.jdbc.SqlScriptsTestExecutionListener.lambda$executeSqlScripts$4(SqlScriptsTestExecutionListener.java:263)
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.TransactionOperations.lambda$executeWithoutResult$0(TransactionOperations.java:68)
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.TransactionTemplate.execute(TransactionTemplate.java:140)
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.TransactionOperations.executeWithoutResult(TransactionOperations.java:67)
    at org.springframework.test.context.jdbc.SqlScriptsTestExecutionListener.executeSqlScripts(SqlScriptsTestExecutionListener.java:263)
    at org.springframework.test.context.jdbc.SqlScriptsTestExecutionListener.lambda$executeSqlScripts$0(SqlScriptsTestExecutionListener.java:185)
    at java.lang.Iterable.forEach(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.test.context.jdbc.SqlScriptsTestExecutionListener.executeSqlScripts(SqlScriptsTestExecutionListener.java:185)
    at org.springframework.test.context.jdbc.SqlScriptsTestExecutionListener.executeSqlScripts(SqlScriptsTestExecutionListener.java:147)
    at org.springframework.test.context.jdbc.SqlScriptsTestExecutionListener.beforeTestMethod(SqlScriptsTestExecutionListener.java:117)
    at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.beforeTestMethod(TestContextManager.java:289)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.java:74)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.java:86)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.SpringRepeat.evaluate(SpringRepeat.java:84)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:251)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:97)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:70)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:190)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:86)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:459)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:678)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:382)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:192)
Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: syntax error at or near "INSERT"
  Position: 1
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.receiveErrorResponse(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2497)
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.processResults(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2233)
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.execute(QueryExecutorImpl.java:310)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.executeInternal(PgStatement.java:446)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.execute(PgStatement.java:370)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.executeWithFlags(PgStatement.java:311)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.executeCachedSql(PgStatement.java:297)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.executeWithFlags(PgStatement.java:274)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.execute(PgStatement.java:269)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.init.ScriptUtils.executeSqlScript(ScriptUtils.java:605)
    ... 35 more
```

Can you please suggest me on this??

Comment: have you tried the query with schema qualified something like this, 
INSERT INTO <schema>.employee (emp_name) VALUES ('Jhon Dave');

Comment: still getting the same error

Answer (score 2):

An easier way to test a database would be to use a h2 database with autoconfigs. If you place a "data.sql" with your insert statement and a "schema.sql" file with the employee table schema into the "resources" folder of your test folder, spring boot will automatically load those 2 scripts without a problem, im using this myself all the time and it works like a charm.

Here is some code: https://howtodoinjava.com/spring-boot2/h2-database-example/